# How to make a field dependant on another field inside one model in django

Tags: django

I would like the field joinkey pass the primary key of the project into the function random_int to generate a default joinkey for every new model being created. Is there a way to do this or am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

```
class Project(MainAbstractModel):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    joinkey = models.IntegerField(default=random_int(self.pk))

    def other_user(self):
        return self.users.exclude(username=user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the @property decorator to handle that.

```
class Project(MainAbstractModel):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")

    @property
    def joinkey(self):
        return random_int(self.pk)

    @joinkey.setter
    def joinkey(self, value):
        # handle setting a joinkey if need be
        pass

    def other_user(self):
        return self.users.exclude(username=user.username)
```

Comment: If I did it like this it esets the joinkeys of every object each time I save a new object into the database:  @joinkey.setter
    def joinkey(self, value):
        joinkey = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)